# Can't create a selectable and remember the elements checked inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery UI and I'm trying to do a selectable that shows the 7 days after from today. Example:

Friday Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday

Each one is an item where you can select one of them. So I use .selectable(). I want that when I click on one element, it shows a new list with 3 elements:
Morning
Afternoon
Night

In the new list you can select the items and It have to remember which ones where clicked.

If you change your selected item in the first selectable, the day list, you have to show again the list Morning, afternoon and night, but clean, and you can select again wherever you want. But the fact Its if we back to the previous day or to another day, we have to remember the selected items and shows it selected.

This is my code, I know It's so bad but I'm starting on this.

```
        dias.forEach((dia) => {
            switch (dia) {
                case 0: $("#selectable").append(`<li class="ui-widget-content">Domingo</li><ol id="select-result" hidden>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content"> Mañana</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Tarde</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Noche</li>
                  </ol > `);
                    break;
                case 1: $("#selectable").append(`<li class="ui-widget-content">Lunes</li><ol id="select-result" hidden>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content"> Mañana</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Tarde</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Noche</li>
                  </ol > `);
                    break;
                case 2: $("#selectable").append(`<li class="ui-widget-content">Martes</li><ol id="select-result" hidden>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content"> Mañana</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Tarde</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Noche</li>
                  </ol > `);
                    break;
                case 3: $("#selectable").append(`<li class="ui-widget-content">Miercoles</li><ol id="select-result" hidden>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content"> Mañana</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Tarde</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Noche</li>
                  </ol > `);
                    break;
                case 4: $("#selectable").append(`<li class="ui-widget-content">Jueves</li><ol id="select-result" hidden>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content"> Mañana</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Tarde</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Noche</li>
                  </ol > `);
                    break;
                case 5: $("#selectable").append(`<li class="ui-widget-content">Viernes</li><ol id="select-result" hidden>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content"> Mañana</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Tarde</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Noche</li>
                  </ol > `);
                    break;
                case 6: $("#selectable").append(`<li class="ui-widget-content">Sabado</li><ol id="select-result" hidden>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content"> Mañana</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Tarde</li>
                    <li class="ui-widget-content">Noche</li>
                  </ol > `);
                    break;
            }
        });
    });

    $(function () {

        $("#selectable").selectable({
            selected: function (event, ui) {
                $("#select-result").show();
                $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
            }

        });
        $("#select-result").selectable({
            selected: function (event, ui) {

                if ($(ui.selected).hasClass("selected")) {
                    $(ui.selected).removeClass("selected");
                }
                else $(ui.selected).addClass("selected");

            }
        });
    });


</script>
</head>

<body>


<ol id="selectable">
</ol>

</body>

</html>
```

My problem is when I click on Saturday for example, It shows Morning, afternoon and night. But when I click on other day doesn't show the other "list", It shows the same list with the same selected items and what I want is that It shows empty without selections to check the new items and when switch to other day remember the elements selected

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: when I change HTML content, I have to update/redo the functions bound to selectors, since the HTML changed. Right? Maybe if you change it to do the bindings just after your switch statement (with an .unind() appropriately inserted), that will change it for you.

That is, make it more like:

```
dias.forEach((dia) => {
    switch (dia) {
        ...
        ...
    }
});

$("#selectable").unbind().selectable({
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        $("#select-result").show();
        $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
    }
});
    $("#select-result").unbind().selectable({
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.selected).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(ui.selected).removeClass("selected");
        }
        else $(ui.selected).addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

});